# Dell Mobile Connect for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, dell, phone

So Dell announced their new mobile connect software at CES this year, and it looks really useful. Here's a link: http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-mobile-connect/ab/dell-mobile-connect. It pretty much gives you access to your phone on your computer, which lets you text, call, and even use apps. I've been using Ubuntu for two years now, and it always seems like Linux gets all of these features first, so I was wondering: Does Ubuntu have some sort of software that does some of the same things that this mobile connect does?

Comment: [KDEConnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) maybe?  It is one of the first ones I have seen for Linux.  Or check http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try the amazing Chrome extension Vysor. 
Makes you control your phone's screen in a similar way as Dell Connect.